# Friend methods error

Tags: c++

I get this error message:

```
'friend' used outside of class.
```

My header has this line

```
private:
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, card&);
```

and in the `cpp` file it is

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& outStream, card& card)
{
    Suit suit=card.getSuit();
    Rank rank=card.getRank();
    string str;
    switch(rank)
        { /*...*/ }
    outStream<<str;
    return outStream;
```

like this.

I searched but mostly it says that I need same class without friend but I tried, and it did not work. Can you please give me some suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: Outputting a `card` should not need to modify the object. Pass it by const reference instead.

Comment: Did you try not using `friend` outside the class, as the error message suggests?

Answer (score 15):

Remove the `friend` in the `.cpp` file.  It is only required (and allowed) within the `class` definition in the header file.

In the header file, you declare that the operator is your friend:

```
private:
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, card&);
```

This is a property of the class.

In the source file, just define the operator "normally":

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& outStream, card& card)
{
    // ...
}
```

Here, `friend` does not make sense: Friend of whom?  Multiple classes might declare the operator as friend.